# nth child in html doubts

Tags: html, css

I expect `p:nth-child(2)` highlight the second item of the `p`, which is the second paragraph, but why in this case the first paragraph were highlighted? I removed the `h1`, `p:nth-child(2)` highlighted the 3rd item, why? Is h1 consider a `p` too?

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Because h1 is also a child.

Comment: Use `p:nth-of-type(2)`instead.

Comment: element:nth-child(expression)Out of all the children of any type, find out the the `n-th` child based on the `expression` and if it's of the `element` type, highlight it. nth-of-type does what you want to do in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p:nth-child(2)` means that if `p` is the second element in the collection then it is highlighted. Use `p:nth-of-type(2)` to highlight exactly the second `p` element in the combined collection of `p` and `h1`.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this:

```
<div>
    <h1></h1> //Also considered as a child of the div
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

So if you write `p:nth-child(2)` the first `p` will be selected because the `h1` is also a child of the div.